# Nginx (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream; YunoHost / Duniter

Tags: nginx, debian

**Hardware**

- Raspberry Pi 2

**Software**

- Debian

  - YunoHost

    - Duniter

When I try accessing Duniter's web application page https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui, I receive the typical nginx `502 Bad Gateway` error.

I've also tried accessing the webui after starting duniter webstart with the same result.

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ duniter webstart
Starting duniter_default daemon...
duniter_default daemon started. PID: 3453
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ duniter status
Duniter is running using PID 3453.
```

/etc/hosts

```
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters

127.0.1.1       Xroklaus
```

/var/log/nginx/duniter-folatt.nohost.me-access.log

```
83.163.103.119 - - [24/Oct/2017:21:14:29 +0000] "GET /yunohost/sso/assets/img/logo-ynh-white.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 2722 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/yunohost/sso/?r=aHR0cHM6Ly9kdW5pdGVyLWZvbGF0dC5ub2hvc3QubWUvd2VidWk=" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - folatt [25/Oct/2017:05:43:11 +0000] "GET /webui HTTP/1.1" 502 236 "https://forum.yunohost.org/t/duniter-web-interface-502-bad-gateway/3686" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:05:43:11 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10934 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - folatt [25/Oct/2017:05:43:13 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.json HTTP/1.1" 200 2156 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:05:43:13 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.css HTTP/1.1" 200 113127 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:08:51:24 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - folatt [25/Oct/2017:08:51:25 +0000] "GET /webui HTTP/1.1" 502 236 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:08:51:25 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10934 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:08:51:27 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.css HTTP/1.1" 200 113127 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - folatt [25/Oct/2017:08:51:27 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.json HTTP/1.1" 200 2156 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:09:22:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - folatt [25/Oct/2017:09:22:34 +0000] "GET /webui HTTP/1.1" 502 236 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:09:22:34 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.js HTTP/1.1" 200 10934 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - folatt [25/Oct/2017:09:22:35 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.json HTTP/1.1" 200 2156 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
83.163.103.119 - - [25/Oct/2017:09:22:35 +0000] "GET /ynhpanel.css HTTP/1.1" 200 113127 "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
```

/var/log/nginx/duniter-folatt.nohost.me-error.log

```
2017/10/24 21:06:30 [error] 3086#0: *307 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /cesium HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/cesium", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me"
2017/10/24 21:06:50 [error] 3086#0: *307 [lua] access.lua:120: Redirection to an external domain aborted, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /yunohost/sso/?r=aHR0cHM6Ly8xOTIuMTY4LjE3OC4xMC95dW5vaG9zdC9zc28v HTTP/1.1", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me", referrer: "https://192.168.178.10/yunohost/admin/"
2017/10/24 21:07:01 [error] 3086#0: *307 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me", referrer: "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/yunohost/sso/"
2017/10/24 21:07:50 [error] 3084#0: *308 [lua] access.lua:120: Redirection to an external domain aborted, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /yunohost/sso/?r=aHR0cHM6Ly8xOTIuMTY4LjE3OC4xMC95dW5vaG9zdC9zc28v HTTP/1.1", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me"
2017/10/24 21:08:25 [error] 3084#0: *308 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me"
2017/10/24 21:09:50 [error] 3084#0: *308 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me", referrer: "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/yunohost/admin/"
2017/10/24 21:10:28 [error] 3084#0: *308 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me", referrer: "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/yunohost/sso/info.html"
2017/10/24 21:10:33 [error] 3084#0: *308 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me"
2017/10/24 21:10:39 [error] 3084#0: *308 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me", referrer: "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/yunohost/sso/info.html"
2017/10/24 21:10:43 [error] 3084#0: *308 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me", referrer: "https://duniter-folatt.nohost.me/webui"
2017/10/25 05:43:11 [error] 3087#0: *1772 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me", referrer: "https://forum.yunohost.org/t/duniter-web-interface-502-bad-gateway/3686"
2017/10/25 08:51:25 [error] 3087#0: *2138 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me"
2017/10/25 09:22:34 [error] 3084#0: *2208 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 83.163.103.119, server: duniter-folatt.nohost.me, request: "GET /webui HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9220/", host: "duniter-folatt.nohost.me"
```

/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
2017/10/24 19:20:39 [notice] 10189#0: signal process started
2017/10/24 19:23:00 [notice] 10378#0: signal process started
2017/10/24 19:35:43 [info] 735#0: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:63
2017/10/24 19:35:43 [info] 735#0: [lua] init.lua:57: SSOwat ready
2017/10/24 20:30:39 [notice] 3081#0: signal process started
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/duniter-folatt.nohost.me.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name duniter-folatt.nohost.me;

    access_by_lua_file /usr/share/ssowat/access.lua;

    include conf.d/duniter-folatt.nohost.me.d/*.conf;

    location /yunohost/admin {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/duniter-folatt.nohost.me-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/duniter-folatt.nohost.me-error.log;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name duniter-folatt.nohost.me;

    ssl_certificate /etc/yunohost/certs/duniter-folatt.nohost.me/crt.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/yunohost/certs/duniter-folatt.nohost.me/key.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # Ciphers with intermediate compatibility
    # https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=nginx-1.6.2&openssl=1.0.1t&hsts=yes&profile=intermediate
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS';

    # Ciphers with modern compatibility
    # https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=nginx-1.6.2&openssl=1.0.1t&hsts=yes&profile=modern
    # Uncomment the following to use modern ciphers, but remove compatibility with some old clients (android < 5.0, Internet Explorer < 10, ...)
    #ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    #ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';

    # Uncomment the following directive after DH generation
    # > openssl dhparam -out /etc/ssl/private/dh2048.pem -outform PEM -2 2048
    #ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/dh2048.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;";

    access_by_lua_file /usr/share/ssowat/access.lua;

    include conf.d/duniter-folatt.nohost.me.d/*.conf;

    include conf.d/yunohost_admin.conf.inc;
    include conf.d/yunohost_api.conf.inc;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/duniter-folatt.nohost.me-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/duniter-folatt.nohost.me-error.log;
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/duniter-folatt.nohost.me.d/yunohost_local.conf

```
server_name $server_name yunohost.local;
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/duniter-folatt.nohost.me.d/duniter.conf

```
location / {
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
       proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy  true;

       proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:10901;
       proxy_redirect          off;

       # Socket.io support
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
       proxy_read_timeout 86400s; 
       proxy_send_timeout 86400s;

    location ~ \.(js|css|woff|woff2|ttf|png) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9220;
        access_by_lua_file /usr/share/ssowat/access.lua;
    }

    location /cesium {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9220;
        access_by_lua_file /usr/share/ssowat/access.lua;
        # Include SSOWAT user panel.
        include conf.d/yunohost_panel.conf.inc;
    }

    location /webui {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9220/;
        access_by_lua_file /usr/share/ssowat/access.lua;
        # Include SSOWAT user panel.
        include conf.d/yunohost_panel.conf.inc;
    }

    location ~ /webmin {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9220$uri;
        access_by_lua_file /usr/share/ssowat/access.lua;
    }

    location ~ /modules {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9220;
        access_by_lua_file /usr/share/ssowat/access.lua;
    }

}
```

Port listening check

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1185/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1185/nginx -g daemo
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1185/nginx -g daemo
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1185/nginx -g daemo
```

Firewall check

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ sudo tcpdump -n icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:41:39.886220 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.169.12: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 513
17:41:39.887065 IP 192.168.178.10 > 84.200.70.40: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 139
17:41:39.888895 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.188.188: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 139
17:41:39.889336 IP 192.168.178.10 > 84.200.69.80: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 139
17:41:39.889890 IP 192.168.178.10 > 91.239.100.100: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 378
17:41:39.890214 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.169.40: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 139
17:41:39.894840 IP 192.168.178.10 > 141.255.128.100: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 513
17:41:39.895405 IP 192.168.178.10 > 141.255.128.101: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 513
17:41:39.895908 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.233.43.71: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 529
17:41:39.896370 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.234.141.66: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 139
17:41:39.896843 IP 192.168.178.10 > 213.73.91.35: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 139
17:41:39.897407 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.234.186.18: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 28172 unreachable, length 139
17:42:09.946485 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.169.12: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 513
17:42:09.948459 IP 192.168.178.10 > 84.200.69.80: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 139
17:42:09.949718 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.169.40: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 139
17:42:09.954162 IP 192.168.178.10 > 213.73.91.35: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 139
17:42:09.954658 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.233.43.71: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 529
17:42:09.956123 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.188.188: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 139
17:42:09.970844 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.234.141.66: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 139
17:42:09.971808 IP 192.168.178.10 > 141.255.128.100: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 513
17:42:09.972294 IP 192.168.178.10 > 141.255.128.101: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 513
17:42:09.976717 IP 192.168.178.10 > 91.239.100.100: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 369
17:42:09.984867 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.234.186.18: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 139
17:42:10.045260 IP 192.168.178.10 > 84.200.70.40: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 58304 unreachable, length 139
17:42:39.987486 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.169.12: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 221
17:42:39.987988 IP 192.168.178.10 > 84.200.70.40: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 85
17:42:39.990722 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.188.188: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 85
17:42:39.991245 IP 192.168.178.10 > 84.200.69.80: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 85
17:42:39.991925 IP 192.168.178.10 > 91.239.100.100: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 133
17:42:39.992926 IP 192.168.178.10 > 80.67.169.40: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 85
17:42:39.995829 IP 192.168.178.10 > 141.255.128.100: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 221
17:42:39.996330 IP 192.168.178.10 > 213.73.91.35: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 85
17:42:39.997135 IP 192.168.178.10 > 141.255.128.101: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 221
17:42:39.997563 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.233.43.71: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 133
17:42:39.998120 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.234.141.66: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 85
17:42:39.998721 IP 192.168.178.10 > 89.234.186.18: ICMP 192.168.178.10 udp port 39307 unreachable, length 85
^C
36 packets captured
36 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original settings were correct and I probably did not start duniter, then started duniter after changing the settings.

The important thing is that duniter needs to be running..

```
admin@Xroklaus:~ $ duniter status
Duniter is running
```

..and port 9220 needs to be open.

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :9220
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9220                :::*                    LISTEN      1775/duniter_defaul
```